# Variables wrong after python script conversion. They belong to the moment of conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have a python script that I converted with pyinstaller.

```
pyinstaller -F "myscript.py" # it's the command I used
```

For example, myscript.PY does some commands to retrieve a variable of a path:

```
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) # this finds the path of the script
elements = os.listdir(path) # this find the files in "path"
```

But when I run myscript.EXE it goes to find the elements at the moment of conversion and NOT the elements of the path where I POST LOCATED myscript.EXE.

Is there a workaround? What can I do?

Comment: Does `__file__` work? Eg, `from pathlib import Path` `path = Path(__file__).resolve()`

Comment: it's the same, I tested it

Comment: Try `os.getcwd()`

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks!!